# HTML5 Validation for Zend Studio

Tags: eclipse, validation, html, zend-studio

I'm trying to keep my project as error free as possible, but all my phtml files that contain `<nav>`, `<aside>`, `<article>` and other HTML5 tags cause errors.
How can I configure the validator to recognize these new elements?

Have tried to request support  from the source here
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=10463

No answers so far

Comment: no answer and googling just returns me to my own question?

Comment: just facing same problem, you can disable in preferences / web / html / validator / uknown tags

Answer (score 3):

Use the [HTML5 DTD](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/contrib/catalogs/html5) from Komodo, which is an extension of the XHTML DTD, as a new mapping in the [Eclipse XML Catalog](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog).

```
<!--
   HTML 5 DTD

   This is the same as HTML 4 Transitional except for
   updates for the HTML 5 specication.
-->

<!--================ Character mnemonic entities =========================-->

<!ENTITY % HTMLlat1 PUBLIC
   "-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN"
   "html5-lat1.ent">
%HTMLlat1;

<!ENTITY % HTMLsymbol PUBLIC
   "-//W3C//ENTITIES Symbols for XHTML//EN"
   "html5-symbol.ent">
%HTMLsymbol;

<!ENTITY % HTMLspecial PUBLIC
   "-//W3C//ENTITIES Special for XHTML//EN"
   "html5-special.ent">
%HTMLspecial;

<!--================== Imported Names ====================================-->

<!ENTITY % ContentType "CDATA">
    <!-- media type, as per [RFC2045] -->

<!ENTITY % ContentTypes "CDATA">
    <!-- comma-separated list of media types, as per [RFC2045] -->

<!ENTITY % Charset "CDATA">
    <!-- a character encoding, as per [RFC2045] -->

<!ENTITY % Charsets "CDATA">
    <!-- a space separated list of character encodings, as per [RFC2045] -->

<!ENTITY % LanguageCode "NMTOKEN">
    <!-- a language code, as per [RFC3066] -->

<!ENTITY % Character "CDATA">
    <!-- a single character, as per section 2.2 of [XML] -->

<!ENTITY % Number "CDATA">
    <!-- one or more digits -->

<!ENTITY % Date "CDATA">
    <!-- one or more digits -->

<!ENTITY % LinkTypes "(alternate | archives | author | bookmark | contact | external | first | help | icon | index | last | license | next | nofollow | noreferrer | pingback | prefetch | prev | search | stylesheet | sidebar | tag | up)">
    <!-- space-separated list of link types -->

<!ENTITY % MediaDesc "(all|braille|embossed|handheld|print|projection|screen|speech|tty|tv)">
    <!-- single or comma-separated list of media descriptors -->

<!ENTITY % URI "CDATA">
    <!-- a Uniform Resource Identifier, see [RFC2396] -->

<!ENTITY % UriList "CDATA">
    <!-- a space separated list of Uniform Resource Identifiers -->

<!ENTITY % Datetime "CDATA">
    <!-- date and time information. ISO date format -->

<!ENTITY % Script "CDATA">
    <!-- script expression -->

<!ENTITY % StyleSheet "CDATA">
    <!-- style sheet data -->

<!ENTITY % Text "CDATA">
    <!-- used for titles etc. -->

<!ENTITY % FrameTarget "(_blank | _parent | _self | _top)">
    <!-- render in this frame -->

<!ENTITY % Length "CDATA">
    <!-- nn for pixels or nn% for percentage length -->

<!ENTITY % MultiLength "CDATA">
    <!-- pixel, percentage, or relative -->

<!ENTITY % Pixels "CDATA">
    <!-- integer representing length in pixels -->

<!ENTITY % Boolean "(true|false)">

<!-- these are used for image maps -->

<!ENTITY % Shape "(rect|circle|poly|default)">

<!ENTITY % Coords "CDATA">
    <!-- comma separated list of lengths -->

<!-- a color using sRGB: #RRGGBB as Hex values -->
<!ENTITY % Color "CDATA">

<!-- There are also 16 widely known color names with their sRGB values:

    Black  = #000000    Green  = #008000
    Silver = #C0C0C0    Lime   = #00FF00
    Gray   = #808080    Olive  = #808000
    White  = #FFFFFF    Yellow = #FFFF00
    Maroon = #800000    Navy   = #000080
    Red    = #FF0000    Blue   = #0000FF
    Purple = #800080    Teal   = #008080
    Fuchsia= #FF00FF    Aqua   = #00FFFF
-->

<!--=================== Generic Attributes ===============================-->

<!-- core attributes common to most elements
  id       document-wide unique id
  class    space separated list of classes
  style    associated style info
  title    advisory title/amplification
-->
<!ENTITY % coreattrs
 "id          ID             #IMPLIED
  class       CDATA          #IMPLIED
  style       %StyleSheet;   #IMPLIED
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED"
  >

<!-- internationalization attributes
  lang        language code (backwards compatible)
  xml:lang    language code (as per XML 1.0 spec)
  dir         direction for weak/neutral text
-->
<!ENTITY % i18n
 "lang        %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  xml:lang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  dir         (ltr|rtl)      #IMPLIED"
  >

<!-- attributes for common UI events
  onclick     a pointer button was clicked
  ondblclick  a pointer button was double clicked
  onmousedown a pointer button was pressed down
  onmouseup   a pointer button was released
  onmousemove a pointer was moved onto the element
  onmouseout  a pointer was moved away from the element
  onkeypress  a key was pressed and released
  onkeydown   a key was pressed down
  onkeyup     a key was released
-->
<!ENTITY % events
 "onclick     %Script;       #IMPLIED
  ondblclick  %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onmousedown %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onmouseup   %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onmouseover %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onmousemove %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onmouseout  %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onkeypress  %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onkeydown   %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onkeyup     %Script;       #IMPLIED
<!-- HTML 5 Mouse Events - Events triggered by a mouse, or similar user actions: -->
  ondrag        %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when an element is dragged -->
  ondragend     %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run at the end of a drag operation -->
  ondragenter   %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when an element has been dragged to a valid drop target -->
  ondragleave   %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when an element leaves a valid drop target -->
  ondragover    %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when an element is being dragged over a valid drop target -->
  ondragstart   %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run at the start of a drag operation -->
  ondrop        %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when dragged element is being dropped -->
  onmousewheel  %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when the mouse wheel is being rotated -->
  onscroll      %Script;      #IMPLIED      <!-- Script to be run when an element's scrollbar is being scrolled -->
 "
  >

<!-- attributes for elements that can get the focus
  accesskey   accessibility key character
  tabindex    position in tabbing order
  onfocus     the element got the focus
  onblur      the element lost the focus
-->
<!ENTITY % focus
 "accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED
  tabindex    %Number;       #IMPLIED
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED"
  >

<!-- HTML 5 core attributes -->
<!ENTITY % html5attrs
 "contenteditable    %Boolean;     #IMPLIED
  contextmenu        ID            #IMPLIED
  draggable          (true | false | auto) #IMPLIED
  hidden             (hidden)      #IMPLIED
  item               CDATA         #IMPLIED
  itemprop           CDATA         #IMPLIED
  spellcheck         %Boolean;     #IMPLIED
  subject            ID            #IMPLIED
  contextmenu        ID            #IMPLIED
  contextmenu        ID            #IMPLIED
  contextmenu        ID            #IMPLIED
  contextmenu        ID            #IMPLIED
 "
  >


<!-- Media Events - Events triggered by medias like videos, images and audio.
     Applies to all HTML 5 elements, but is most common in media elements, such
     as audio, embed, img, object, and video. -->

<!ENTITY % html5mediaevents
 "onabort               %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run on an abort event -->
  oncanplay             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media can start play, but might has to stop for buffering -->
  oncanplaythrough      %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media can be played to the end, without stopping for buffering -->
  ondurationchange      %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the length of the media is changed -->
  onemptied             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when a media resource element suddenly becomes empty (network errors, errors on load etc.) -->
  onended               %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media has reach the end -->
  onerror               %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when an error occurs during the loading of an element -->
  onloadeddata          %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media data is loaded -->
  onloadedmetadata      %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the duration and other media data of a media element is loaded -->
  onloadstart           %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the browser starts to load the media data -->
  onpause               %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media data is paused -->
  onplay                %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media data is going to start playing -->
  onplaying             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media data has start playing -->
  onprogress            %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the browser is fetching the media data -->
  onratechange          %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the media data's playing rate has changed -->
  onreadystatechange    %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the ready-state changes -->
  onseeked              %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when a media element's seeking attribute is no longer true, and the seeking has ended -->
  onseeking             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when a media element's seeking attribute is true, and the seeking has begun -->
  onstalled             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when there is an error in fetching media data (stalled) -->
  onsuspend             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when the browser has been fetching media data, but stopped before the entire media file was fetched -->
  ontimeupdate          %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media changes its playing position -->
  onvolumechange        %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media changes the volume, also when volume is set to "mute" -->
  onwaiting             %Script;      #IMPLIED  <!-- Script to be run when media has stopped playing, but is expected to resume -->
 "
>







<!ENTITY % attrs "%coreattrs; %i18n; %events; %html5attrs;">

<!--=================== Text Elements ====================================-->

<!ENTITY % special.extra
   "object | img | map | iframe">

<!ENTITY % special.basic
    "br | span | bdo">

<!ENTITY % special
   "%special.basic; | %special.extra;">

<!ENTITY % fontstyle.basic "small | i | b | u">

<!ENTITY % fontstyle "%fontstyle.basic;">

<!ENTITY % phrase.extra "sub | sup">
<!ENTITY % phrase.basic "em | strong | dfn | code | q |
                   samp | kbd | var | cite | abbr | acronym">

<!ENTITY % phrase "%phrase.basic; | %phrase.extra;">

<!ENTITY % inline.forms "input | output | select | textarea | label | button |
                         datetime | datetime-local | data | month | week |
                         time | number | range | email | url | menu |
                         datalist">

<!-- these can occur at block or inline level -->
<!ENTITY % misc.inline "ins | del | script">

<!-- these can only occur at block level -->
<!ENTITY % misc "noscript | %misc.inline;">

<!ENTITY % inline "a | %special; | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %inline.forms;">

<!-- %Inline; covers inline or "text-level" elements -->
<!ENTITY % Inline "(#PCDATA | %inline; | %misc.inline;)*">

<!--================== Block level elements ==============================-->

<!ENTITY % heading "h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6">
<!ENTITY % lists "ul | ol | dl">
<!ENTITY % blocktext "pre | hr | blockquote | address | article | aside |
                      summary | mark">

<!ENTITY % block
    "p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | fieldset | table |
    header | footer | section | hgroup | main | nav | dialog | figure |
    datagrid | canvas | audio | video | source | embed | keygen |
    progress | ruby">

<!-- %Flow; mixes block and inline and is used for list items etc. -->
<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">

<!--================== Content models for exclusions =====================-->

<!-- a elements use %Inline; excluding a -->

<!ENTITY % a.content
   "(#PCDATA | %special; | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %inline.forms; | %misc.inline;)*">

<!-- pre uses %Inline excluding img, object, big, small -->

<!ENTITY % pre.content
   "(#PCDATA | a | %special.basic; | %fontstyle.basic; | %phrase.basic; |
       %inline.forms; | %misc.inline;)*">

<!-- form uses %Flow; excluding form -->

<!ENTITY % form.content "(#PCDATA | %block; | %inline; | %misc;)*">

<!-- button uses %Flow; but excludes a, form, form controls, iframe -->

<!ENTITY % button.content
   "(#PCDATA | p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; |
      table | datagrid | br | span | bdo | object | img | map |
      %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %misc;)*">

<!--================ Document Structure ==================================-->

<!-- the namespace URI designates the document profile -->

<!ELEMENT html (head, body)>
<!ATTLIST html
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  xmlns       %URI;          #FIXED 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  manifest    %URI;          #IMPLIED
  >

<!--================ Document Head =======================================-->

<!ENTITY % head.misc "(script|style|meta|link|object)*">

<!-- content model is %head.misc; combined with a single
     title and an optional base element in any order -->

<!ELEMENT head (%head.misc;,
     ((title, %head.misc;, (base, %head.misc;)?) |
      (base, %head.misc;, (title, %head.misc;))))>

<!ATTLIST head
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  profile     %URI;          #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- The title element is not considered part of the flow of text.
       It should be displayed, for example as the page header or
       window title. Exactly one title is required per document.
    -->
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST title 
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- document base URI -->

<!ELEMENT base EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST base
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  target      %FrameTarget;  #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- generic metainformation -->
<!ELEMENT meta EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST meta
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  http-equiv  CDATA          #IMPLIED
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED
  content     CDATA          #REQUIRED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  >

<!--
  Relationship values can be used in principle:

   a) for document specific toolbars/menus when used
      with the link element in document head e.g.
        start, contents, previous, next, index, end, help
   b) to link to a separate style sheet (rel="stylesheet")
   c) to make a link to a script (rel="script")
   d) by stylesheets to control how collections of
      html nodes are rendered into printed documents
   e) to make a link to a printable version of this document
      e.g. a PostScript or PDF version (rel="alternate" media="print")
-->

<!ELEMENT link EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST link
  %attrs;
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  sizes       %Number;       #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- style info, which may include CDATA sections -->
<!ELEMENT style (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST style
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  type        (text/css)     #REQUIRED
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  scoped      (scoped)       #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- script statements, which may include CDATA sections -->
<!ELEMENT script (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST script
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  type        (text/javascript)  #REQUIRED
  language    CDATA          #IMPLIED
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  async       (async)        #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- alternate content container for non script-based rendering -->

<!ELEMENT noscript %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST noscript
  %attrs;
  >

<!--======================= Frames =======================================-->

<!-- inline subwindow -->

<!ELEMENT iframe %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST iframe
  %coreattrs;
  %html5attrs;
  name        NMTOKEN        #IMPLIED
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED
  height      %Length;       #IMPLIED
  width       %Length;       #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  sandbox     (allow-forms | allow-same-origin | allow-scripts)        #IMPLIED
  seamless    CDATA          #IMPLIED
  srcdoc      CDATA          #IMPLIED
  >

<!--=================== Document Body ====================================-->

<!ELEMENT body %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST body
  %attrs;
  onload      %Script;       #IMPLIED
  onunload    %Script;       #IMPLIED
<!-- HTML 5 Window Event Attributes -->
  onafterprint    %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run after the document is printed -->
  onbeforeprint   %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run before the document is printed -->
  onbeforeonload  %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run before the document loads -->
  onerror         %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when an error occur -->
  onhaschange     %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the document has change -->
  onmessage       %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the message is triggered -->
  onoffline       %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the document goes offline -->
  ononline        %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the document comes online -->
  onpagehide      %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the window is hidden -->
  onpageshow      %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the window becomes visible -->
  onpopstate      %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the window's history changes -->
  onredo          %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the document performs a redo -->
  onresize        %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the window is resized -->
  onstorage       %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when a document loads -->
  onundo          %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when a document performs an undo -->
  onunload        %Script;   #IMPLIED        <!-- Script to be run when the user leaves the document -->
  >

<!ELEMENT div %Flow;>  <!-- generic language/style container -->
<!ATTLIST div
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Paragraphs =======================================-->

<!ELEMENT p %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST p
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Headings =========================================-->

<!--
  There are six levels of headings from h1 (the most important)
  to h6 (the least important).
-->

<!ELEMENT h1  %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h1
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT h2 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h2
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT h3 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h3
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT h4 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h4
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT h5 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h5
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT h6 %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST h6
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Lists ============================================-->


<!-- Unordered list -->

<!ELEMENT ul (li)+>
<!ATTLIST ul
  %attrs;
  >

<!-- Ordered (numbered) list -->

<!ELEMENT ol (li)+>
<!ATTLIST ol
  %attrs;
  start       %Number;       #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  reversed    (reversed)     #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- list item -->

<!ELEMENT li %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST li
  %attrs;
  value       %Number;       #IMPLIED
  >

<!-- definition lists - dt for term, dd for its definition -->

<!ELEMENT dl (dt|dd)+>
<!ATTLIST dl
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT dt %Inline;>
<!ATTLIST dt
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT dd %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST dd
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Address ==========================================-->

<!-- information on author -->

<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA | %inline; | %misc.inline; | p)*>
<!ATTLIST address
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Horizontal Rule ==================================-->

<!ELEMENT hr EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST hr
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Preformatted Text ================================-->

<!-- content is %Inline; excluding 
        "img|object|small|sub|sup" -->

<!ELEMENT pre %pre.content;>
<!ATTLIST pre
  %attrs;
  >

<!--=================== Block-like Quotes ================================-->

<!ELEMENT blockquote %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST blockquote
  %attrs;
  cite        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  >

<!--=================== Inserted/Deleted Text ============================-->

<!--
  ins/del are allowed in block and inline content, but its
  inappropriate to include block content within an ins element
  occurring in inline content.
-->
<!ELEMENT ins %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST ins
  %attrs;
  cite        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  datetime    %Datetime;     #IMPLIED
  >

<!ELEMENT del %Flow;>
<!ATTLIST del
  %attrs;
  cite        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  datetime    %Datetime;     #IMPLIED
  >

<!--================== The Anchor Element ================================-->

<!-- content is %Inline; except that anchors shouldn't be nested -->

<!ELEMENT a %a.content;>
<!ATTLIST a
  %attrs;
  %focus;
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  target      %FrameTarget;  #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  media       CDATA          #IMPLIED
  ping        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  >

<!--===================== Inline Elements ================================-->

<!ELEMENT span %Inline;> <!-- generic language/style container -->
<!ATTLIST span
  %attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT bdo %Inline;>  <!-- I18N BiDi over-ride -->
<!ATTLIST bdo
  %coreattrs;
  %html5attrs;
  %events;
  lang        %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  xml:lang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  dir         (ltr|rtl)      #REQUIRED
  >

<!ELEMENT br EMPTY>   <!-- forced line break -->
<!ATTLIST br
  %coreattrs;
  %html5attrs;
  >

<!ELEMENT em %Inline;>   <!-- emphasis -->
<!ATTLIST em %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT strong %Inline;>   <!-- strong emphasis -->
<!ATTLIST strong %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT dfn %Inline;>   <!-- definitional -->
<!ATTLIST dfn %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT code %Inline;>   <!-- program code -->
<!ATTLIST code %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT samp %Inline;>   <!-- sample -->
<!ATTLIST samp %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT kbd %Inline;>  <!-- something user would type -->
<!ATTLIST kbd %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT var %Inline;>   <!-- variable -->
<!ATTLIST var %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT cite %Inline;>   <!-- citation -->
<!ATTLIST cite %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT abbr %Inline;>   <!-- abbreviation -->
<!ATTLIST abbr %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT q %Inline;>   <!-- inlined quote -->
<!ATTLIST q
  %attrs;
  cite        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  >

<!ELEMENT sub %Inline;> <!-- subscript -->
<!ATTLIST sub %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT sup %Inline;> <!-- superscript -->
<!ATTLIST sup %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT i %Inline;>   <!-- italic font -->
<!ATTLIST i %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT b %Inline;>   <!-- bold font -->
<!ATTLIST b %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT small %Inline;>   <!-- smaller font -->
<!ATTLIST small %attrs;>

<!--==================== Object ======================================-->
<!--
  object is used to embed objects as part of HTML pages.
  param elements should precede other content. Parameters
  can also be expressed as attribute/value pairs on the
  object element itself when brevity is desired.
-->

<!ELEMENT object (#PCDATA | param | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*>
<!ATTLIST object
  %attrs;
  %html5mediaevents;
  data        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  height      %Length;       #IMPLIED
  width       %Length;       #IMPLIED
  usemap      %URI;          #IMPLIED
  name        NMTOKEN        #IMPLIED
  tabindex    %Number;       #IMPLIED
  <!-- HTML 5 attributes -->
  form        CDATA          #IMPLIED
  >
```

**References**

- [HTML5.1 DTD Reference](http://sgmljs.net/docs/w3c-html51-dtd.html)